# Best way to test command line tools?

Tags: testing, command-line, automation

We have a large collection of command-line utilities that we write ourselves and use frequently. At the moment, testing them is very cumbersome and consequently, we don't do as much testing as we aught to.

I am wondering if anyone can suggest good techniques or tools for doing a good job of this kind of thing.

This is UNIX.

Comment: Are you using or writing/producing the command line utilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba) is a [Cucumber](http://cukes.info) extension for testing command line applications written in any programming language.

To use it, you will need ruby to run the tests, but the purpose of aruba is to provide a library of pre-defined step definitions so that you won't need to write any ruby code to make a workable test suite.  (Though at some point you probably will want to write a bit of ruby to make a few custom steps.)

You can see a sophisticated example of a command line tool tested with aruba here: [jingweno/gh](https://github.com/jingweno/gh/tree/master/features)

Answer (score 16):

I recommend structuring your command line tool's code so that the command line utility is a client to a library of functions and/or classes.

Rather than simply using std::cout to print output, have the libraries function take an ostream reference that defaults to std::cout. When you are testing, provide a std::stringstream to collect the output.

Finally, simply compare your utility's output with expected results using your favorite unit testing framework.

(I apologize for the C++ specific example... I'm sure there are ways to do similar things in other languages too).

Answer (score 12):

You can write tests that resemble an interactive shell session using [Cram](https://bitheap.org/cram/). It has flexible test specification format that allows you to match output using Perl regex or shell-like wildcards. Cram will replay commands from the test, compare output to the reference, and report differences.

Comment: Just FYI that Cram isn't supported on Windows.  There are some hacks with using bash, but I don't think any of those workarounds are viable.   The maintainers don't see Windows support a high priority.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to call them from a shell script (batch file, on MS operating systems), redirect the output to a file, then scan the file programmatically to ensure that it has the correct output.  I'm not aware of a testing framework that automates this for you, but it should be fairly straight forward to set it up yourself.

Comment: Yes - I'd hoped that someone might be aware of a framework or tool. I was thinking about knocking one up myself as your right, it wouldn't be too difficult.

Cheers. Tom

Answer (score 3):

[Bats (Bash Automated Testing System)](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats) by Sam Stephenson. It is tiny, written purely in shell and has a nice set of features.

Previously suggested Aruba looks interesting, but in some cases it might be quiet an overkill in terms of dependencies (ruby, cucumber)

Answer (score 2):

I did a little bit of this (a loooong time ago hehe) using [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to check that what happened was what I, umm, expected

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a tool "Exactly"
https://github.com/emilkarlen/exactly

It executes the thing to test in a temporary sandbox directory. 
The README contains a number of examples.

A test of a hypotethical program "classify-files-by-moving-to-appropriate-dir" can look like this:

```
[setup]

dir input
dir output/good
dir output/bad

file input/a.txt = <<EOF
GOOD contents
EOF

file input/b.txt = <<EOF
bad contents
EOF

[act]

classify-files-by-moving-to-appropriate-dir GOOD input/ output/

[assert]

dir-contents input empty

exists output/good/a.txt : type file
dir-contents output/good num-files == 1

exists output/bad/b.txt : type file
dir-contents output/bad num-files == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use perl with [Test::more](http://search.cpan.org/~exodist/Test-Simple-1.001014/lib/Test/More.pm) library, which provides a great framework for testing CLIs.
Though primarily designed for unit testing, you could extend it to test user workflows.

Some of the methods:

```
 # Various ways to say "ok"
  ok($got eq $expected, $test_name);
  is  ($got, $expected, $test_name);
  isnt($got, $expected, $test_name);

  # Rather than print STDERR "# here's what went wrong\n"
  diag("here's what went wrong");

  like  ($got, qr/expected/, $test_name);
  unlike($got, qr/expected/, $test_name);

  cmp_ok($got, '==', $expected, $test_name);
```

[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)[automation](/questions/tagged/automation)[testing](/questions/tagged/testing)[perl-testing](/questions/tagged/perl-testing)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this from a batch file oder windows scripting host.

But i promise to use a task scheduler like (http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm) or other free/professional software.

There you can easy copy/paste the commandline-parameters which you should vary on, when you wanna test your software for about many 100 times?!