# python: functional/acceptance tests of command line scripts

Tags: python, functional-testing, acceptance-testing

In python, if I make a web application I can write functional/acceptance tests with selenium. And I can use mocking for test some functions.

how I can to write functional/acceptance tests of command line scripts?

exist some packages to this purpose?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353198/best-way-to-test-command-line-tools

Comment: thanks @Dyrborg I can started with this, but the answer of your link is a ruby solution, if I use this : 1) I need read about ruby 2) I need set my continuous integration server with a ruby and a python environment

Comment: @JuanPablo for 1) the answer say *you won't need to write any ruby code to make a workable test suite*. Anyway why don't use even `unittest` and set `sys.argv` by using [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to split command line arguments. To test the output `pexpect` is the best choice. IMHO write your own framework based on these tools is a 1-2 days effort that give to you exactly what you need.... and you will be in a unittest context: mocking, patching fake filesystem... and so on