# How to run/execute a unit testing framework like "catch2" in Unix Bash?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unix, automated-tests, catch2

I am trying to learn testing with makefiles . I  searched online for a framework. Many people talked about "catch2" so I downloaded it. I read the tutorial in git and I've searched about it in many other webpages. I wrote this : `mytests` (without any suffix in the name)  to check `myprogram.cpp`.

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN 
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("maximum space is","[myprogram]"){
    REQUIRE( myprogram(test.in1)==50)
    REQUIRE( myprogram(test.in2)==20)
    REQUIRE( myprogram(test.in3) ==1100)
    REQUIRE( myprogram(test.in4)==23)
    REQUIRE( myprogram(test.in5)==10);
}
```

The are many articles about how to write this and how to add features and specialisations or how to run it while choosing which tests to run and other stuff...
**But I could not find somewhere explicitly explaining how to run this** . I am a beginner . I know that I can run a single test in my program which takes as input a file, like that :  `./myprogram test.in1` . So, what I need to type to use this testing framework??

Comment: You would need to compile your test program and run it as you would do with any C++ program. Without knowing any details of the specific test framework, I assume that the `REQUIRE` lines would try to call a function named `myprogram` with the value of a structure field `in1` etc. of a variable `test` and compare the return value. This does **not** call a program named `myprogram` as you seem to think.

Comment: Rename `mytests` to `mytests.cpp`, then compile it, and run it.

Comment: @Bodo so how do I this?

Comment: With the little information in the question it is difficult to give specific instructions. Please [edit] your questions and add details about the tests you want to automate. Describe **in the question** what exactly you would do manually. If you want to run `./myprogram test.in1` and check the output, then a C++ unit test framework is not the correct tool. I never used a test tool for command line programs. See e.g. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/01/11/command-line-interface-testing-tools/ or https://stackoverflow.com/q/353198/10622916 or https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelltestrunner